# MP4 not playing in IE9/Chrome

Tags: h.264, mp4

I have an iOS app which takes advantage of the camera to create and save videos, whicha re then uploaded to a web server. However, when I try to view these videos on the server using IE9, I get an audio stream, but I only see the poster. When viewed in Chrome, I *do* see a video, but it is rotated 90 degrees from what it should be.

The MP4 files already use the H.264 encoding. When I tried converting the MP4 to FLV and using it in a flash player, it was still rotated 90 degrees. I have tried videojs but to no avail. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the videos aren't playing on IE9.

The videos are rotated because iOS devices record in a fixed orientation and then set the `rotate` metadata tag as appropriate.  Some players recognize and act on that tag, many do not.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409094/85950) for instructions on rotating the video using FFmpeg, though most any video manipulation software should be able to do this.

Comment: It seems you're right about the metadata, but the command provided in the other answer doesn't work.

Comment: I got it to work, -vf "transpose=2" needs to go after input_file. See my comment in the other answer. But it still isn't clear to me who to find out the current rotation of a given video file.

Comment: There isn't yet a way to do the rotation automatically, but you can look for the `rotate` tag using `ffprobe` (which is usually bundled with FFmpeg) and then use that to determine the `transpose` call.  I feel like there's already a short shell script for doing that floating around SO, but I couldn't find it just now.

Comment: I did that yesterday using Ruby. It's very clumsy, but I suppose it fulfills my needs for now. Thanks for your help!