# video rotation with ffmpeg doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to rotate video using ffmpeg. The original video is rotated 270°. When I run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -i IMG_3290.MOV -vcodec libx264 -preset faster -s 568x320 \
-vf "transpose=2" -strict -2 -b 5000k -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 16000 -ab 32000 \
IMG_3290.MP4
```

I got no error, but the output video is still rotated and contains the tag `rotate: 270`.

Comment: adding the following to configure of ffmpeg solved my problem:
--enable-libxvid --enable-avfilter --enable-libgsm --enable-libvpx --enable-libopenjpeg

Though, don't know which of them exactly solved it...

Answer (score 0):

As a 270 or 90 rotation on a MP4 suggest a video recorded from an iPhone... or another mobile device, you should consult:

[video captured from iphone gets rotated when converted to .mp4 using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408542/video-captured-from-iphone-gets-rotated-when-converted-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg)
,
in some case

```
 -vf "transpose=1"
```

doesn't work, so check the other option -vflip.

Comment: Don't forget any rotation metadata that may be present. See [iPhone recorded videos getting rotated on Windows systems](http://superuser.com/questions/564233/iphone-recorded-videos-getting-rotated-on-windows-systems).