# video concating in FFmpeg from front and back camera creating a video flip

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, ffmpeg

When concating a video from front camera and back camera in FFmpeg the video from the front camera is flipped 180 degrees, please help ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [video captured from iphone gets rotated when converted to .mp4 using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408542/video-captured-from-iphone-gets-rotated-when-converted-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

Flip video horizontally:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vf hflip -c:a copy OUTPUT
```